Cannot override method retainAll() of java Collection Interface
I am trying to implement the Collection interface of the java.util package by class ImplementCollectionInterface. Here the java compiler is giving an error:

ImplementCollectionInterface is not abstract and does not override abstract method retainAll(Collection) in Collection

However, I have overriden the retainAll() method.
Note: Currently I am not focusing on the logical operation to be performed inside retainAll(). I expect it to work as far as I am returning something inside that overridden method. Also - The goal is to do a custom implementation so I have this file saved as CollectionInterface.java and it has public class with same name which has the main method to further like instantiate some other class and pass its object to ImplementCollectionInterface class.
The code is given below -
import java.util.*;

class ImplementCollectionInterface<E> implements Collection {
    E[] data;
    private int size;

   public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
       for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
           data[i] = null;
       }
       size = 1;
       return true;
    }
}

//Collection Interface retainAll method details - 

boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c);


If you're overriding methods, always use @Override. It will tell you where you're going wrong. Incidentally, class names should be noun-based, not verb-based

It needs to be implements Collection<E>

Oh! such a silly mistake I have done. Well thanks)) the error has gone!

The class ImplementCollectionInterface should be defined in a file name ImplementCollectionInterface.java, not CollectionInterface.java. Further, the sentence “it has public class with same name” makes no sense, as you can’t have two classes with the same name. And you must implement all methods of an interface, not just one.

The generic specification you have is inconsistent.
Either you meant to implement a generic Collection (e.g., a Collection<E> where E matches the generic type parameter of the Collection), in which case the signature of your retainAll method is correct:
class ImplementCollectionInterface<E> implements Collection<E> {
    // Here -----------------------------------------------^

Or you meant to implement a raw Collection, in which case the retainAll method should also refer to a raw parameter:
class ImplementCollectionInterface<E> implements Collection {
    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection c) {
        // Here -----------------------^

Note that in either case the class still won't compile as its missing many other methods you still need to implement, but that should clear up the specific error with the retainAll method.
